# Tool to forward a localhost port to the Internet

Tags: gratis, web-apps, web-development

I am looking for an easy way to forward a server running on localhost to a subdomain on a website. I used to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), but now they require that you pay to use a custom subdomain. I don't need to host for a long time, just a few minutes so that people can preview my websites from their own devices. I'm running on Mac OS X, so a Mac app or *nix tool will work.

Comment: operating system?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt see updated question.

Comment: If your other devices are on the same LAN as the server why not just to is connect as 'http:`//_server_ip_address_/ - providing all of your internal links are to relative addresses (good pratice) it should work fine.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I would like to use it for short-term deployment (e.g. send a link to someone, then host it long enough for them to view it, take it down again). If it's not possible, I could use Heroku, etc. to deploy. I would just prefer to have a easy+quick way to host.

Comment: @xǝlɐ - I would suggest rewording your answer to show that other people, in other locations, are going to be doing the testing - it doesn't read that way at the moment.

Comment: @SteveBarnes thanks for the suggestion, it seemed clear in my head :-)

Comment: What I do in similar situations: Using access rules. Basically, "deny all" and "accept from <my_local_net>" when it shouldn't be accessible from the outside, temporarily removing the "deny all" when I want it accessed. Would that work for you? Also, what web server are you using (Apache, Nginx, …)? Plus: with "localhost", do you mean the literal binding to `127.0.0.1`? If so, alternatively to my access rules, you could have it bound to that only long-term, and for the short test phase add the host's "normal address" (or "bind to all interfaces").